# Finite extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, fields, p-adic-numbers, completion

Is there any finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ which is not the completion of a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ at some place over $p$?

Analogously in equicharacteristic, if $k=\overline {\mathbb F_p}$ , is there any finite extension of $k((t))$ which doesn't arise from a finite extension of $k(t)$?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the isomorphism type of a simple extension of a nonarchimedean field is locally constant with respect to the coefficients of a defining polynomial, so at least in characteristic zero, you can choose suitably nearby rational coefficients to get a number field that completes to the $p$-adic field you want.

Comment: I believe the result Scott is referring to is "Krasner's Lemma".

Comment: The answer is no, for the reason S. Carnahan gave (think he meant *complete* nonarchimedean field).

Comment: @S. Carnahan: Thank you very much for this answer. 
Is there any way to  have the same result on a purely inseparable extension of $k[[t]]$ ?

Comment: I think you mean $k((t))$ (and not $k[[t]]$) and $k(t)$ (and not $k[t]$). 

Comment: Thank you, Jason and George.  The name slipped my mind, and so did the completeness condition.

Comment: See also Corollary to Prop. 4, chap. II, par. 2 of Lang "Algebraic Number Theory" (p44 second ed.).

Comment: The truly analogue question in char $p$ is when the coefficient field is finite. But all finite extensions of such a field are again isomorphic to a Laurent power series ring over a (possibly larger) finite field.